# Store CSS value in JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, css

My CSS

```
.h1-modified{
    color: green;
}
```

My JavaScript file

```
var h1Modified = [HERE IS SOME CODE MISSING];
```

I want to store the color of the html class `.h1-modified` in the JavaScript variable `h1Modified`.

If it works `alert(h1Modified);` outputs `green`.

PROBLEM: `.h1-modified` isn't assigned to any HTML element. I have to access the CSS file directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you want to read a CSS property.. I don't think you can read it directly from CSS, but you can read it from an element that has this class

```
const tag = document.getElementById('my_id');
const styles = window.getComputedStyle(tag);
const tagColor = style.getPropertyValue('color');
```

You can read more about it here: [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration).

Or you could just read a color from an elemenet

```
const color = document.getElementById("tag").style.color;
```

PS: Oh, you need to parse CSS file? Well, parsers are available in any language, JavaScript is one of them. Take a look at [JSCSSP](http://glazman.org/JSCSSP/). It can parse CSS files, but keep in mind that this parsed file **won't necessarily** be the same that is used to render the website. Or that styles found in the file will be applied to your HTML tags.

Comment: I don't want to modify CSS (class) from JavaScript, I just want to read it.

Comment: @Sr.Schneider Do you want to read a color of a HTML element or CSS class?

Comment: I have to access the CSS file via JavaScript. Looks like this isn't possible.

Comment: @Sr.Schneider Please see my editted answer. Consider accepting it if it solved your problem, or tell me what I can do to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I know someone already has answered it. But here is a Jquery version:

```
$('#id').css('color', 'blue'); //To change
```

to store as var:

```
var x = $('#id').css('color');  //will return the colour
```

reference:

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Is something like `var x = $('#id').css('color');` available in plain JS?

Comment: try this :
var x = document.getElementById("myId").style.color
I think it will do the job

Comment: The question asked for JavaScript not jQuery

Comment: read the answer again and then read the comments before commenting